# Hide facebook app from search

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm adding an iFrame page to our facebook fan page, it's got a newsletter signup form on it, however I am stuck on something.

If our fan page is called blahblah, the signup page is called "BlahBlah Insider Info". When I search for Blahblah, the app appears before the fan page, which is not good!

How can I make it so it doesn't appear in search and can only be accessed from our fan page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO** it's not currently possible. In addition, our search takes into account previous app/page usage so depending on when you visited the app, it may appear in a different order to you, than it does to others.

Comment: Has this changed in the last two years? Some apps are only used for authentication and their URL isn't meant for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that it is not possible to remove an Application from the search results.

To solve my problem I used a *dirty hack* to redirect the user when I detected that he was accessing the Application Page and not my real Page Tab.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'apps.facebook.com') > -1){
    echo "<script type="text/javascript">
    top.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/_MY_PAGE_TAB_';
    </script>";
  }
}
```

Facebook use the subdomain "apps.facebook.com" for the Application Pages but "www.facebook.com" for Page Tabs.

It needed to be Javascript because if I would have use PHP it would have only redirected the iframe and not the complete page.

Comment: Why not just remove the 'app on facebook' integration settings entirely if you don't want users landing there?

Comment: @Igy I don't remember exactly the error message but Facebook didn't let me configure a Page Tab without a Canvas (App on Facebook).

Comment: Are you referring to an error 191 in the auth flow? you shouldn't need a canvas/website configured to work around that

Answer (score -1):

i think this happens only to the developer account. if you sign in with a different account you will not see your app. correct