# How do I keep an app from appearing as a search result in Facebook

Tags: facebook

We have a website Facebook "app" for talking to our iPhone client and web client.  When you search for us in Facebook the app shows up in addition to our page.  Clicking on it produces a page not found error.  I couldn't find anyplace in the app settings to keep the app from appearing in searches. Ideas?

Comment: The page not found error is a currently open bug report ( https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204664672932552 ) , i'll add an answer now explaining how to remove the search result, which is a different (but in this case related) issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904530/hide-facebook-app-from-search

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this might help at all, but something similar was happening to me and ended up discovering that my Computer was the problem. It was everything cached on my browser. Do you get the same result if you try on another computer? Or maybe logged in as someone else?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to remove an app from the search index once added - I'm not sure if this is likely to change in the near future