# Hide Facebook App Page From Search

Tags: facebook, search, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide facebook app from search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904530/hide-facebook-app-from-search)

Okay, I know that this question was asked here:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6904530/hide-facebook-app-from-search

And the answer was that it's not 'currently' possible.

HOWEVER, Facebook changes things every damn day (and that post is from August 1st), so 'currently' has absolutely no meaning to me in this case.

So... having said that... is it possible to hide an App page from appearing in Facebook Search?

The reasoning behind this is that it's meant to be just a Page Tab, and when a user clicks on the App Page, it's just a blank wall (why would anyone be posting to the app's wall? I don't know).

I am aware that Facebook changed it so you no longer have to submit an app to search for it to appear -- it's automatic.  BUT WHY WOULD THEY DO THAT?!

I can't put it in Sandbox Mode, because then no one will be able to use a Page Tab.

So, it seems that all of my options are exhausted.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: What is even more frustrating is that said Page Tab is NOT EVEN set up to be an 'App' on Facebook (what used to be 'Canvas', I believe?)... it's JUST a Page Tab in the App Settings Page.

Comment: Thanks for reiterating that this is a duplicate.Does Facebook change every two months?  Yes.  Has the answer to this question changed?  Perhaps.  I have every intention of finding out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option you can define a custom tab on your app which simply redirects away and set this tab as default landing tab for your app page.

Comment: Thanks so much, Anatoly!  Awesome workaround... can't believe I didn't think of that; works like a charm.  (Might I add that it's REALLY unfortunate that this question was closed by 'the powers that be' because no one mentioned this workaround on the initial question, and it is indeed a great solution... so, in retrospect, I am VERY glad I re-asked the question.)