# Facebook Apps in the Search

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a website that required a Facebook Fan page, an app for sharing and authorizing and another app as a tab app for the page.

Now I'm facing a problem that when one searches the Facebook, all these three instances appears in the search, and the bad thing is that the Official Fan Page is third in the results :(

I wonder if there's any way to remove these apps from search results without removing them as I'd like to save all the likes these apps have received?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904530/hide-facebook-app-from-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove apps from search, but as per https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ the app profile pages are deprecated and will be removed in a few months

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that social discovery is disabled (Settings > Advanced > Social Discovery).

Edit:  Since this doesn't work (see @Igy's comment), I would try to merge these apps into one.

Comment: That setting doesn't affect search visibility of the app profile page itself

Comment: Not that I know of.  Pick one app, and try to replicate the functionality of the other two.