# How Can I make a facebook application not appear in search?

Tags: facebook

I have an application that we want only specific users to have access to, but almost public at the same time. The sandbox mode isn't sufficient because then only developers have access to the application

What I'm looking for is a way to keep my application semi-private but not appear in search results on facebook if someone is typing in a similar name

Any ideas would be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904530/hide-facebook-app-from-search

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple roles available, not just developer. You can leave it in sandbox mode and add users at "testers". There are 4 roles altogether: Admin, Developer, Tester, Insights User. Just click on the "Roles" item on the left nav when editing the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe sandbox mode is the only option. You could, of course, create an ambiguous name for your app and implement your main page code in such a way that it redirects users away when they try to access the page unless they have specific user ids.

Are you currently developing an app and need access restricted or do you just wish for your app to be hidden? Why don't you want to set users as developers? If it has to do with the required phone number and/or credit card info I might suggest creating a [secret group](http://www.facebook.com/groups) and inserting that group into the tester category in the developer app. Then you can just add people to the secret group and they'll instantly be granted access to your sandboxed app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply keybored. Basically we want users to be able to access the app who aren't extremely tech savvy but for testing purposes only. I guess my main issue is that someone can hit the "go to app" button on the page that's public and install the application to their facebook page. Giving them access to our test app

Comment: We'd like to keep it private but allow anyone who's not an fb developer access (which sandbox will only allow), so keeping sandbox disabled but privatizing the app for the moment to the public